# [partially solved]Javascript Regex for allowing all non-english alphabets , hyphen and underscore and block everythinh else?

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, I need to `allow alphabets of all (or preferrably accented characters and chinese) languages, hyphen and underscore.`
I need to disallow `special characters and numerals.`
I looked at many answers but couldn't find anything that matches my needs.

Allowed patterns:

```
ab_c
åb-ç
的å
```

Disallowed patterns

```
å!_
å123
!_!
```

Please share with me if you have a snippet..
I am on a deadline and freaking out :(

Edit:
The following regex matches all non-English characters. If I can alphabets and hypehn and underscore, it would be complete

```
/[^\u0000-\u007F]/.test("ji");
```

I got this snippet from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46413244

I added alphabtes, -, _ like below but it fails. Can anyone help?

```
/[^a-z\_\-\u0000-\u007F]/.test("ji");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the regex you gave at the end of the answer incorrectly excludes _ and -. The same thing that allows _ and - is `/[^a-z\u0000-\u007F]|[_-]/`

Edit: But what you really want is: `/[^\u0000-\u007F]|[a-zA-Z-_]/`

Or manually exclude all the special characters you want to: `/[^(0-9!?@#$%^&*()+\\=[\]{};':"|,.<>/]/`

Comment: Hi Thanks
`/[^a-z\u0000-\u007F]|[_-]/` this fails  when we enter `a` as input. Also it allows special characters. Can you help me fix that?

Comment: Ok. How is that?

Comment: Your edited answer works!
`\u0000-\u007F1` allowed special chars so I did like this:  `/[^\u0000-\u007F]|[a-zA-Z-_]/.test(x) && ! ([^(0-9!?@#$%^&*()+\\=[\]{};':"|,.<>/]/.test(x))`

It allows other special chars (eg `£` ) but it was good enough for me..
Thanks

Comment: Ok can you mark it as the accepted answer